# Malloc an array of string arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a array made of strings arrays:

> char ***t = NULL;

I am filling it dynamically with strings `s`, and so I use the `realloc` function like this:

```
int sumchars = 0;
for i, j... :
   s = result(i, j);
   sumchars += strlen(s);
   t = realloc(t, sumchars * sizeof(char));
   t[i][j] = s;
```

This gives me a Segmentation fault. Do you know why please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `realloc` in this case. Try this instead:

```
t = realloc(t, ROW*sizeof(char**));   
for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
{
    t[i] = NULL;
    t[i] = malloc(COL*sizeof(char *));
}
for(...)
{
    s = result(i, j);
    t[i][j] = s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I don't need to use `realloc`, what should I do?

Comment: Use `malloc`. Using the method I have explained, a string of any length can be assigned to `t[i][j]`.

Comment: So I use the last piece of code of your message by changing realloc in malloc?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... Do I have to do t = malloc(sizeof(char**)); for every i, j??

Comment: Yes. You need to do that if you do not want to concatenate all the strings to a single location.

Comment: I don't necessarily want that. So I am okay to use malloc. However I don't understand something in the piece of code right before your EDIT. When you do `**t = s`, what I would like to do is `t[i][j] = s`. How to specify that?

Comment: What is the limit of `i` and `j` ? See the edit again.

Comment: `t = malloc(ROW * sizeof(char**));
*t = malloc(COL * sizeof(char *));

t[i][j] = s;` gives me a Segmentation fault.

Comment: @Arnaud; You should learn more about pointers and its implementations.  On SO, answers will not always provide exact code. You need to extract the ideas given in answer and then implement it. BTW, I reduced the answer and wrote the code for you.